# fit all components in one row in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating a report in SSRS and trying to fit all the characters in one row for the column but although I have enlarged the size of the column the data does not fit in one line but the SQL query shows in one line. The sample picture is given below. Can anyone help me with this?

sql example: HYDROCARBON CONSTRUCTION CO % L H GUNN PO BOX 53495 HOUSTON TX 77052-3495

[image]

Comment: Are they all different fields? Would need to concatenate them if they are.

Comment: I would guess that the text contains hidden characters such as a carriage returns. You will probably need to strip those out first either in your dataset query of within the textbox expression.

Comment: No, they are within the same field.

Comment: no there are no hidden characters. eg: HYDROCARBON CONSTRUCTION CO % L H GUNN PO BOX 53495 HOUSTON TX 77052-3495

Comment: Are you certain there are no hidden chars? Have you tested this? In SSMS try something like `declare @t varchar(1000); set @t=(SELECT top 1 myCol from myTable where myCol like 'HYDROCARBON CO%'); print @t;` and see if the result is on a single line, if not then you must have hidden chars such as char(13), char(10).

Comment: Hi Alan, Thank you for the code. wow, I got in in four rows. I tried to solve it, but since those lines are separated by ENTER, how can put it in one line?  The result is below. HYDROCARBON CONSTRUCTION CO
% L H GUNN
PO BOX 53495
HOUSTON TX 77052-3495

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost certainly that your data contains hidden characters, probably carriage return and/or linefeed.

To replace these values, use the follow expression.

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(Fields!myFieldName.Value, Chr(13), ""), Chr(10), "")
```

If there are more then you can either extend the expression or better still use regex to strip out the unwanted characters.

Comment: Thank you, Alan. Appreciate your help. I did it in a different way. just copy and paste the related data into excel and updated the SQL data based on that excel data. It worked. I did not do anything rather than coping and replacing data again but worked.