# multiple line print result should display in one line

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a SQL-based question. when I run the select statement in my table it shows in one line but when I print it, it comes in multiple rows. because of this when I create SSRS report the data shows in multiple rows.
eg: SQL select statement result:
HYDROCARBON CONSTRUCTION CO % L H GUNN PO BOX 53495 HOUSTON TX 77052-3495

and when I filter by the WHERE clause I did not get any result.

eg: select emplpyer_name from employers where employer_name = 'HYDROCARBON CONSTRUCTION CO % L H GUNN PO BOX 53495 HOUSTON TX 77052-3495'

but when I print it, it gives results in four rows like below.

I have run the bolow code and got 4 line result. but I want it in one line when I print it:

declare @t varchar(1000);
set @t=(SELECT Employer_name as a from EMPLOYERS where e_name like 'HYDROCARBON CO%');
print @t;

HYDROCARBON CONSTRUCTION CO
% L H GUNN
PO BOX 53495
HOUSTON TX 77052-3495

it is the address column and I am not able to get this result when I filter by the WHERE clause as well. it shows blank. I want all these multiple rows in one line when I print as well.It would be appreciated if someone helps me with this.
and SSRS result I got like below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dydQQ.jpg)

I have tried to concatinate it but still gave multiline result.

Comment: Does the answer here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951518/replace-a-newline-in-tsql

Comment: I've added an answer to the original question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74996823/fit-all-components-in-one-row-in-ssrs

Comment: Thank you Edmcoff and Alan. it worked.